# Make Mist pass skip semitransparent objects

Tags: cycles-render-engine, transparency, render-passes

I am having problems with the Mist pass. I have search other questions but didn't find the answer.

As you can see, I got an ocean (left) and a "river" (right). Don`t mind about the river disappearing towards the right, I need that way but doesn´t affect my problem (but I wanted to keep the settings as I have in the big project).

When trying to get the Mist pass, both objects are semitransparent, as you can see here:
[image: mist]

Also the Z pass gets crazy:
[image]

I think is because they both have glass and transparent material, and also volume absorption.

The sun is 0.8 in size and 5 Max bounces.

So, the question is: How can I get the Mist pass "skip" the transparency settings of both objects?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a new render layer in which the material is overriden by some material that has no transparency, and enable mist for that render layer. Then use the mist pass from that layer to combine over the other layers.

[image]

(click on the image to enlarge)

Comment: Thank you cegaton! Perfectly resolved and in an easy way, without having to do much extra work. Maybe in Blender's updates they will make it even more easier!

Answer (score 1):

As long as it doesn't affect your other render passes, you can go to the *View Layers Tab > Passes > Data* set the *Alpha Threshold* to zero.

This will effectively make the *Depth Pass* ignore the alpha of all objects that are transparent or translucent to any degree. It will treat them as solid objects.

This option is only available in Cycles, AFAIK EEVEE already ignores transparency for *Depth* passes.

[image]